# Analysing a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is an $n-$ dimensional vector space.
If $W$ is a subspace such that under any isomorphism from $V$ to $V$ we have $T(W)$ and $W$ have a non trivial intersection.Then what can be said about W?

Comment: I know that "What can be said about $W$?" is a broad question, but try asking yourself "What can be said about the dimension of $W$?"

Comment: For starters, if $k = \dim W \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, can you find an automorphism $T$ of $V$ such that $T(W)$ intersects $W$ trivially? Think about $\mathbb{R}^k$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes if i have a transformation $T:R^n\to R^n$ such that $T(x_1,x_2.....x_n)=(x_n,x_{n-1}.....x_2,x_1)$.This is clearly an automorphism.and if we defie $W=(x_1,x_2,...x_{\rfloor(\frac  {n}{2})},0,0...0)$.then under this isomorphism this $W$ will have a  trivial intersection with $T(W)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;\dim V=k\le n\;$, then for any isomorphism $\;T:V\to V\;$ we certainly have $\;\dim T(W)=\dim W=k\;$ , so

$$n\ge\dim(T(W)+W)=\dim T(W)+\dim W-\dim(T(W)\cap W)\implies$$

$$\dim(T(W)\cap W)\ge2k-n\stackrel{\text{given}}\ge1\implies k\ge\frac{n+1}2$$

and this inequality is sharp: if

$$\dim W=k<\frac{n+1}2\;,\;\;\text{say}\;\;W=\text{Span}\,\{w_1,...,w_k\}$$

then completing this basis to one of $\;V\; $: $\{w_1,...,w_k,v_{k+1},..,v_n\}\;$, 
 we get  that the following linear map determined by the its action on this basis:

$$T:V\to V\;,\;\;\begin{cases}T(w_i):=v_{k+i}\;,\;\;&1\le i\le k\\{}\\T(v_{k+j}):=w_j\;,\;\;&1\le j\le k\\{}\\T(v_{k+j}):=v_{k+j}\;,\;\;&j>k\end{cases}$$

is an isomorphism with $\;T(W)\cap W=\{0\}\;$ .

Comment: I dont understand the step where you wrote$dim$$T (W)$intersection$W$$\ge 2k-n $ is ok..but why should it be greater than equal to $1$..because if $a\ge b$,$a\ge c$ that should mean $a\ge max$ {$b,c$}

Comment: @Upstart I'ts greater than or equal one because we assume it is not trivial, and the inequality follows from what is written there and from $\;\dim T(W)+\dim W=k+k=2k\;$